# Cordova Phonegap local notifications not working

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I wanted to first say this is a really nice plugin (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) but having some difficulties getting it working.

I am using an Android and Phonegap CLI. I have tried both CLI 5.0 and now Phonegap 3.5.0, this is my config.xml:

`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />`

In my config.xml I have tried all these combinations:

```
<plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification"  spec="0.8.1" source="pgb" />
<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" />
<plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" source="pgb" />
```

However the notifications do not appear - nothing happens on the phone - nothing, nada, zilch. I have also downloaded the KitchenSink App (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/example) and installed on Phonegap build and my phone and nothing again happens..

This is my code on index.html so when the phone fires it should register a local notification asap:

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.registerPermission(function (granted) {
    // console.log('Permission has been granted: ' + granted);
});

cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: 1,
    title: 'Reminder',
    text: 'Dont forget to pray today.',
    every: 'minute',
    icon: 'res://icon',
    smallIcon: 'res://ic_popup_sync'
});
```

I also tried

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: 2,
    text: "Good morning!",
    firstAt: tomorrow_at_8_am,
    every: "day" // "minute", "hour", "week", "month", "year"
});
```

Even the KitchenSink app is not working - nothing happens on the phone??

My Android version is: 5.1.1

**How can I get local notifications to appear in Phonegap?**

Comment: Have you verified that the deviceready event has fired?

Comment: Yes, the app responds with this. I have done console.log and various other tests both in Phonegap build and making a .apk on the phone - the kitchen sink app is not working either

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Hi, i m just trying out with the kitchensink app. Will let you know by tomorrow.But one thing i noticed while downloading the sample code is that the plugin folder is not getting extracted properly. I m not able to find 'de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification' folder inside the plugins. I could see only 'de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification' file of size 1kb. So could you confirm that your plugin is installed properly by checking the same in your plugins folder?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Any update on this? Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: How are you trying? Notifications should only appear when the app is in background, and probably you are testing in foreground.

Comment: @Del you can see local notifications while on the app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too have spent many hours trying to get this plugin working & I have, but i do find it to be one of the most temperamental.

Within your js -

```
var testNotifications = function () {

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

  console.warn("testNotifications Started");

  // Checks for permission
  cordova.plugin.notification.local.hasPermission(function (granted) {

    console.warn("Testing permission");

    if( granted == false ) {

      console.warn("No permission");
      // If app doesnt have permission request it
      cordova.plugin.notification.local.registerPermission(function (granted) {

        console.warn("Ask for permission");
        if( granted == true ) {

          console.warn("Permission accepted");
          // If app is given permission try again
          testNotifications();

        } else {
          alert("We need permission to show you notifications");
        }

      });
    } else {

      var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( "/www/" ),
          secondLevelLocation = window.location.protocol +"//"+ pathArray[0],
          now = new Date();


      console.warn("sending notification");

      var isAndroid = false;

      if ( device.platform === "Android" ) {
        isAndroid = true;
      }

      cordova.plugin.notification.local.schedule({
          id: 9,
          title: "Test notification 9",
          text: "This is a test notification",
          sound: isAndroid ? "file://sounds/notification.mp3" : "file://sounds/notification.caf",
          at: new Date( new Date().getTime() + 10 )
          // data: { secret:key }
      });

    }

  });

  }, false);

};
```

Now on your html tag -

```
<button onclick="testNotifications()">Test notification</button>
```

That should trigger a notification or warn you that it needs permissions
Also top tip is to make sure your notifications are in a folder in the root of the project. android should be mp3 and ios caf

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1 :for version 3.5.0**

have a look at [plugin's plugin.xml](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/blob/master/plugin.xml). see line 22

```
    <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.6.0" />
```

that means plugin **only supports version greater than 3.6.0** and you are using 3.5.0

**Answer 2 :for version 5.0 or higher**

Try the following code as **index.html**. if it runs perfectly then and other options in to `notification.schedule`.
as we haven't provided time(at) option notification will triggered immediately.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
        function onDeviceReady() {                               
            cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
                id: 1,
                title: "Sample Notification",
                text: "foo",                    
                every: "week",                                        
                data: { meetingId: "123#fg8" }
            });
        };
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```